# How to write query to fetch columns in database using hibernate HQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table in my database, and i want to write query to select all columns in this table.

Comment: [This is how you ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.* from sysobjects a inner join syscolumns b on a.id = b.id and b.name = <table_name>
```

you can query the sysobjects and syscolumns

Sorry this is for SQL Server.

For mysql you can use the tables `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`